# Python TCP Socket Programming

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am having some difficulties getting my program to communicate with the two Digi modems that I have.

```
def sockCon ():
global HOST
global PORT
global TX

TX = "\x7E\x00\x0C\x01\x00\xA5"

BUFFER = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
b = 1
while b == 1:        
    print ('T '+TX)
    s.send(TX.encode('latin-1'))        
    time.sleep(5)
    data = s.recv(BUFFER)
    print ('R '+decode(TX,'latin-1'), BUFFER)
```

Basically the problem is that when it sends it will either send completely wrong or it wont send at all and it will give me this error.

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably should not be doing that encode bit

```
TX = b"\x7E\x00\x0C\x01\x00\xA5"
```

should solve your problem (in python3 you need to send bytes not a string)

```
TX = b"\x7E\x00\x0C\x01\x00\xA5"
s.send(TX)
print( repr(s.recv(BUFFER)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python3x then string is not the same type as for Python 2.x, you must cast it to bytes (encode it).

```
TX = "\x7E\x00\x0C\x01\x00\xA5"
s.send(bytes(TX, 'latin-1'))
```

Comment: I dont think he wants to actually encode as latin 1 ... I think he just wants to send it as bytes (although encoded might be the same) .. (yeah i just tested it encodes to exactly the same bytes with or without the latin1 bit :P)